# What are "values" in autocomplete_light

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I don't understand what values are in the django-autocomplete-light library.

Nor what validate_values() and  choices_for_values() does.

I am instantiating my autocomplete like this:

```
   forms.py
     class MyForm(forms.Form):
        search_field2 = autocomplete_light.ChoiceField('ExperimentationAutocomplete')

   apps.py
     class ExperimentationAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteListBase):
        choices = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc', 'dddd']
```

Comment: Can you show the code of how you are instantiating your autocompletefield?

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation of django-autocomplete-light for you. http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/stable-2.x.x/